# numbering isn't showing with matlab-pretifier package

Tags: matlab, matlab-prettifier

does anybody know why this might be? I tried changing my document class from "Article" to "Beamer" and also tried deleting a bunch of packages but nothing has made the numbering on the Matlab-editor style appear. I copy-pasted the example from the documentation, but everything except the numbering appears. Does anybody know why this might be? Thank you

Example (revised, streamlined attempt):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section*{Problem 1}
We verify the $LU$ decomposition of $T$ by following the $LU$ decomposition algorithm used from Homework 2, onward. This process is iterative, so it is helpful to identify the elements of $L$ by the stage of their iteration.

The algorithm goes like this:\\
\begin{lstlisting}[
style=Matlab-editor,
basicstyle=\mlttfamily,
escapechar=`,
]
function [L,U] = GE(A)
%The square matrix A has LU decomposition
[n,n] = size(A);
for k = 1:n-1

    A(k+1:n,k) = A(k+1:n,k)/A(k,k)
    %each element underneath the k'th diagonal element is
    %divided by said element.
    A(k+1:n,k+1:n) = A(k+1:n,k+1:n) - A(k+1:n,k)*A(k,k+1:n)
    %The elements of the lower-right submatrix of dimension
    %(n-k-1)x(n-k-1) are updated. See figures in the
    %explanation below.
end
L = eye(n,n) + tril(A,-1);
U = triu(A);
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. Can you show us some example code demonstrating the problem, i.e. a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)?

Comment: Yes, thank you, I have added a picture of my situation. matlab-pretifier is used on line 45 within the lstlisting command. I simply copy-pasted the example I wanted to imitate from the documentation, which had numbering, but when I pasted it, the numbering wasn't there. Afterwards, I put my own MATLAB code in place of the example MATLAB code.

Comment: Code as picture is just hopeless. Paste the code in, select it and click the button marked `{}` (or hit Ctrl + K). Also, please show the configuration of the package from the preamble.

Comment: fixed, thanks, code is shown. packages listed first, then the part where I copy-pasted the pretifier example, but put my own MATLAB code in place of theirs

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you need

```
\usepackage[numbered]{matlab-prettifier}
```

to turn on numbering, it's not enabled by default. (You could also have added `numbers=left` to the `lstlisting` options). You also want

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

to get the correct font, as mentioned in the manual of `matlab-prettifier`:

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % you need this to get the fonts right
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[numbered]{matlab-prettifier} % <-- add [numbered]

\begin{document}
The algorithm goes like this:
\begin{lstlisting}[
style=Matlab-editor,
basicstyle=\mlttfamily,
escapechar=`,
]
function [L,U] = GE(A)
%The square matrix A has LU decomposition
[n,n] = size(A);
for k = 1:n-1

    A(k+1:n,k) = A(k+1:n,k)/A(k,k)
    %each element underneath the k'th diagonal element is
    %divided by said element.
    A(k+1:n,k+1:n) = A(k+1:n,k+1:n) - A(k+1:n,k)*A(k,k+1:n)
    %The elements of the lower-right submatrix of dimension
    %(n-k-1)x(n-k-1) are updated. See figures in the
    %explanation below.
end
L = eye(n,n) + tril(A,-1);
U = triu(A);
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, man, this fixed everything AND improved my formatting. It is the best answer. Thank you so much!